# Wait for thread execution inside TIdHttpServer's OnCommandGet event handler

Tags: multithreading, delphi, async-await, idhttp

My Delphi Berlin app uses `TIdHttpServer` to get some data from client via HTTP GET, process it and send it back.

All logic is performed within a single event handler: `OnCommandGet`. The identifier is received in a QueryString, then data will be transformed and returned back to client inside the same `OnCommandGet` event handler.

Data transformation is implemented in a separate thread which uses `PostMessage` to inform the main thread that the worker thread completes the execution and the data is ready to be sent back to client.

The data is sent in a `AResponseInfo.ContentText` property.

My question is:

> How do I make `OnCommandGet` handler *wait* until the worker thread
>   does its job and sends the pointer to a transformed data, so I can get
>   the value and fire it back in a `AResponseInfo.ContentText`?

**UPDATE**
Here is the pseudo-code I want to execute:

```
type
  TMyResponsesArray = array[0..5] of TMyObjectAttributes;
  PMyResponsesArray = ^TMyResponsesArray;

{There will be 6 tasks run in parallel. Tasks' responses
will be stored in the below declared Responses array.}

var
  Responses: TMyResponsesArray;

{Below is a Server handler, which takes the input parameter and calls
a proc which runs 6 threads in parallel. The result of each thread is
stored as an ordered array value. Only when the array is completely
populated, ServerCommandGet may send the response!}

procedure TMainForm.ServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  ObjectId: string;
begin
  ObjectId := ARequestInfo.Params.Values['oid'];
  RunTasksInParallel(ObjectId);
end;

{Below is a procedure invoked by ServerCommandGet. It runs 6 tasks in
parallel. Each of the thread instantiates an object, sets its basic
parameter and fires the method. Each task runs queued. When each thread
completes the job, it sends a WM to the main thread (via ParentHandler
which must accept and process the response.}

procedure TMainForm.RunTasksInParallel(const ObjectId: string);
const
  c: array[0..5] of Byte = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var
  ParentHandle: HWND;
begin

  {running 6 tasks in parallel}
  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      TParallel.For(Low(c), High(c),
        procedure(index: Integer)
        var
          MyObj: TMyObject;
          i: Byte;
        begin
          i := c[index];
          MyObj := TMyObject.Create;

          try
            MyObj.SetMyParameter := Random(10);
            Responses[i] := MyObj.CallMyMethd(ObjectId);

            TThread.Queue(nil,
              procedure
              begin
                SendMessage(ParentHandle,
                  UM_DATAPACKET, i, Integer(@Responses));
              end);

          finally
            MyObj.Free;
          end;

        end);
    end);
end;

{Now the WM handler. It decreases internal task counter and when
TaskCounter = 0, it means that all tasks finished execution and the
Responses array is fully populated. Then we somehow need to pass the
Response array to the ServerCommandGet and send it back to client...}

procedure TMainForm.OnDataPacket(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  i := Msg.WParam;
  Responses := PMyResponsesArray(Msg.LParam)^;

  {Skipped for for brevity:
  When ALL tasks have finished execution, the Responses array is FULL.
  Then all array values are wrapped into XML and sent back to initial
  invoker ** ServerCommandGet ** which must send XML to client.}
end;
```

Comment: If `OnCommandGet` spawns a new thread, you could use `TThread.WaitFor()` (or even `WaitForSingleObject()` directly - Windows only). Or, you could just pass a string pointer to the transformation thread, and associate that string with a `TEvent` object that gets signaled after the string has been populated, and then you can wait on that event.

Comment: Just know that while `OnCommandGet` is blocked in a wait, the server will be blocked from being able to shut down if it needs to, such as at app close. Why are you posting data back to the *main thread* instead of to the server thread that requested it? For that matter, why is the transformation being done in a separate thread at all? `TIdHTTPServer` is multithreaded, `OnCommandGet` runs in its own worker thread to begin with. So why not just do the transformation directly in `OnCommandGet`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I updated the question so you can see (and criticize :) the logic of my app. It has something to do with `Parallel.For()` and `TThread.Queue()`. I still don't understand how to make `ServerCommandGet` wait until all tasks (in separate threads) are processed.

Comment: The threads (tasks) always perform some heavy jobs. Then their results must be shared with main thread which does the following: 1) updates the database on the background; 2) sends assembled XML results back to the HTTP caller. So there is no way I can avoid sending thread execution result to the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of a global `Responses` array is not safe, unless you limit `TIdHTTPServer` to allow only 1 connected client at a time.  Otherwise, you could potentially have multiple clients sending requests at the same time and overwriting each other's values in the array.  Each invokation of `ServerCommandGet()` should use a local array instead.

`TIdHTTPServer` is not designed for the type of asynchronous processing you are attempting to do.  `ServerCommandGet()` must block, as `TIdHTTPServer` sends a response to the client when the `OnCommandGet` handler exits, unless the handler sends a response first, which you are not doing.  So, regarding your task thread management, I would suggest either:

1. getting rid of `TTask.Run()` and have `RunTasksInParallel()` call `TParallel.For()` directly.
2. or at least calling `TTask.Wait()` on the `TTask` object that is calling `TParallel.For()`.

Either way will make `RunTasksInParallel()` block (and thus make `ServerCommandGet()` block) until all tasks have finished. Then you can send the response to the client immediately when `RunTasksInParallel()` exits.  You don't need to wait for the tasks to post `UM_DATAPACKET` to the main thread and round-trip back into `TIdHTTPServer`.  If you are using `UM_DATAPACKET` for other things, that's fine, but I do not recommend using it for your HTTP processing.

Try something more like this instead:

```
const
  MaxResponses = 6;

type
  TMyResponsesArray = array[0..MaxResponses-1] of TMyObjectAttributes;

  {$POINTERMATH ON}
  PMyResponsesArray = ^TMyResponsesArray;

{There will be 6 tasks run in parallel. Tasks' responses
will be stored in the below declared Responses array.}

procedure TMainForm.ServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  ObjectId: string;
  Responses: TMyResponsesArray;
begin
  ObjectId := ARequestInfo.Params.Values['oid'];
  RunTasksInParallel(ObjectId, @Responses);
  {ALL tasks have finished execution, the Responses array is FULL.
  Wrap all array values into XML and send it back to the client.}
end;

{Below is a procedure invoked by ServerCommandGet. It runs 6 tasks in
parallel. Each of the thread instantiates an object, sets its basic
parameter and fires the method.}

procedure TMainForm.RunTasksInParallel(const ObjectId: string; Responses: PMyResponsesArray);
begin
  {running 6 tasks in parallel}
  TParallel.For(0, MaxResponses-1,
    procedure(index: Integer)
    var
      MyObj: TMyObject;
    begin
      MyObj := TMyObject.Create;
      try
        MyObj.SetMyParameter := Random(10);
        Responses[index] := MyObj.CallMyMethd(ObjectId);
      finally
        MyObj.Free;
      end;
    end
  );
end;
```

I would also not recommend doing the database updates in the main thread, either.  If you can't update the database directly in `ServerCommandGet()`, or directly in the individual task threads, then I would suggest having a separate thread dedicated for database updates that you post to as needed. Stay out of the main thread as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you, Remy. An excellent answer and a perfect suggestion. It took me a couple of days to test it and now it works great. That was an `Inc(i)` time you saved me a bunch of time :)

Comment: Remy, you mention that "`TIdHTTPServer` is not designed for the type of asynchronous processing [because]... `ServerCommandGet()` must block". Can you please suggest a right choice of HTTP server? Is there any HTTP server component being able to listen to multiple requests and process them asynchronously without blocks?

Comment: I think that DataSnap will do the job. I read some white papers and now I am still in research, but generally all I need it there.

Comment: Well... the idea with DataSnap doesn't work as my class derives from `TObject` and is not compatible with `TPersistentClass`, required by DataSnap server. So far I have no idea how to assign my class to `PersistentClass` in `DSServerClass1GetClass` event handler :-(

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown the class has to derived from `TPersistent`.

Comment: Is there any technic to _rewrite_ the class so it descends from `TPersistent`?

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown just redeclare it: `MyClass = class(TPersistent) ... end;`